# Given MNC is a straight line,find the value of k.

Tags: vectors

[image]
OMA, ONB and ABC are straight lines.
M is the midpoint of OA.

B is the midpoint of AC.

vectorOA = 6a

vectorOB= 6b

vectorON= kb

where k is a scalar quantity.

Given that MNC is a straight line, find the value of k.

Comment: Can you find OM and/or OC?

Comment: Who is giving upvotes to this kind of low-effort question? (I’m out of votes today sadly) This is the **third** time this user has done this.

Answer (score 1):

AB = 6b- 6a
therefore BC = 6b-6a
MN = MA +AC
= 3a + 12b - 12a
= 12b-9a
since  MNC is on a straight line
MN = kb - 3a
MC = 12b - 9a
therefore k = 4